# Allow cropping after taken

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I want the user to crop the photo to a certain size before saving.  Usually you use `allowsEditing = YES` on `UIImagePickerController` however it does not work well.   As you can see in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3cI4nLksBw&9feature=youtu.be) it bounces back whenever I try to crop or move the crop box. How should I am new to Objective-C so I do not know many ways.  Is there a way to allow cropping after the photo is taken in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard "Move and Scale" features of `UIImagePickerController` you are stuck.

If you don't want to implement this yourself (it's not as hard as it sounds, just a lot of layering of views and coordinate mapping) then you can use a component like [GKImagePicker](https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker) with a resizable crop area:  `self.imagePicker.resizeableCropArea = YES;`

Comment: I want it to be a fixed crop box so that the user cannot change the boundary of the crop box.  Is there a difference between apple standard move and scale or the gkimagepicker crop box.

Comment: Take a look at the referenced component.  The crop size can be specified as a fixed `CGSize` if desired.